# Object field does not keep the value

Tags: c#, .net, object

In the following code, I have instances of object Player that has name, numofmentions, s and salience as its fields. In the second for loop I set the value of val.s for each player object. Then I add them together to form a sum, which is fine. But then in the next(third) for loop, I want to use the values on this val.s of each object, but it returns all zero. Can somebody tell me why? I appreciate your help in advance

```
for (int i=0;i<players.Count;i++) 
{
    myList.Add(new Player {name = players[i], numMention=playersNumMentions[i]});
}

var mySummedList = myList.GroupBy(x => x.name).Select(x => new Player { name = x.Key, numMention = x.Sum(y => y.numMention)});

foreach (var val in mySummedList)
{
    if (val.numMention > 50000) //differs for different problems
    {
        sql = "SELECT COUNT(Actor1Code) AS S FROM [gdelt-bq:full.events] WHERE Year>=" + predictionDate + " AND (Actor1Code ='" + val.name + "' AND ((Actor2CountryCode = '" + mainPlayer1 + "') OR (Actor2CountryCode='" + mainPlayer2 + "')))";
        response = new WebClient().DownloadString(url + "?q=" + Uri.EscapeUriString(sql));
        value = JsonValue.Parse(response);

        result = value as JsonObject;
        var row = result["modelData"]["rows"][0];
        val.s=((int)row["f"][0]["v"]);

        sumOfS += val.s;                
    }         
}

foreach (var val in mySummedList)
{
    if (val.numMention > 50000) //differs for different problems
    {                             
        val.salience = val.s / sumOfS;

        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}: {1}", val.name, val.salience));
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the expected output? If it is between 0 and 1, you should make sure you are not doing the calculations with `int`, which is also returned by `Sum()` if `numMention` is an `int`.

Comment: you mean `val.salience` in third loop is always zero?

Comment: The output(salience) is between 0 and 1, but salience is type double in the class.

Comment: so what is zero in third loop?

Comment: Changed s and sum to be double instead of int and it worked. Thanks you all :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because of this line

```
val.salience = val.s / sumOfS;
```

since `sumOfS` is greater than `val.s` and it is an integer division then the result is zero.

you can change `val.salience` type to double and change the line to

```
val.salience = val.s / (double)sumOfS;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using LINQ's Select, that evaluates the enumerable lazily:

```
.Select(x => new Player { name = x.Key, numMention = x.Sum(y => y.numMention)});
```

If you need to reuse the Player instance, try calling ToList after the select:

```
var mySummedList = myList.GroupBy(x => x.name).Select(x => new Player { name = x.Key, numMention = x.Sum(y => y.numMention)}).ToList();
```

Comment: you mean just substitute { name = x.Key, numMention = x.Sum(y => y.numMention)}); with { name = x.Key, numMention = x.Sum(y => y.numMention)}).ToList(); ?

Answer (score 0):

If Player is a struct it will not work, if it is a class change the foreach instead of doing

```
foreach(var x.....)
```

do

```
foreach(Player x....)
```

and make sure that val.s is getting a value distinct from 0

Comment: Using `var` should be fine since `mySummedList` is an `IEnumerable<Player>`.